# GWT Sample Application

Tags: gwt

I'm new to `GWT`. I created sample application in eclipse. I removed `<h1>Web Application Starter Project</h1>` from `HTML` file in `war` but when I debug that application its shows that text on web page. I cleaned project and also compiled it but its not working. Will you guys please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Part of HTML page

```xml
<!--     <h1>Web Application Starter Project</h1> -->

    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Please give your name:</td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="nameFieldContainer"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="sendButtonContainer"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="color:red;" id="errorLabelContainer"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Which application server are you using ? Jetty, Tomcat, Weblogic.. ? Have you redeployed your WAR file ?

Comment: I didn't configure any server for it. I think its taking default server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse with Jetty, you should stop your application. Then clean your GWT project, build it and start again your application. Finally refresh your browser. You have to do this every time your edit static resources such as HTML files.

Comment: Thanks it helped... I don't know why but it did same before but its not working. Anyway..thnx

Comment: I worked for one year on GWT applications... sometimes you even have to clean outside of Eclipse your files. It's a common problem, and cleaning & cleaning again is often the only solution especially on huge projects (even tough a clean can be 20-30min long).

Comment: no offense `gwt` is similar to `Internet Explorer` for programmer. Its like a trash